# How can I get my citizens to craft bread efficiently?

Tags: towns

I have a town with 18 citizens, a bakery with 6 ovens and 6 tables, 3 mills, and a 5x5 wheat field. All of these things are close together. I have production set to +3 Wheat and +15 bread. My citizens have no other tasks except to keep creating food, yet they somehow always seem to have the bare minimum of food, and every now and then someone starves to death.

What gives?

Comment: do you have raw and prepared foods stockpiles set up? With 3 mills, are they spending all their time milling the wheat into flour? Do you have a huge surplus of flour?